# Find a character within quotes, using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

> 106;"LORDAL La Manicure, ser**;**um do manuzi, wzrost, 5 ml";301*04*334;46;"loksx-la-mainusttej-wzroxst-5-ml";"";"";19.51220;"";"";"thumb23_9671ds359.png"

I want to replace all semicolon (;) characters that are within paired quotes. In the example above I only what to remote the semicolon in:  "ser;um".  After replacement it should look like this:

> 106;"LORDAL La Manicure, serum do manuzi, wzrost, 5 ml";301*04*334;46;"loksx-la-mainusttej-wzroxst-5-ml";"";"";19.51220;"";"";"thumb23_9671ds359.png"

I need use a `preg_replace` function, but I don’t know how to define a pattern.

Comment: meny variants for example \"(.*?)(.*?)\". I need some like this: start with " then any chars and end of string: ". So I must search char ; only between " and "

Comment: You *do not* need a regular expression. You need [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv).

Comment: i try but when user add a ; char, that function don't work property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this pattern

```
;(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/234)